# Can an stasised oponent be executed by a Mutons execute ability?

Tags: xcom-2-war-of-the-chosen

Todays challange just looks awesome, you have a squad of psi operatives and templas supported by a squad of heavy advent infatry.

The Muton has the Execute ability, which I luckily never encoutnered in the battlefield before. It kills an adjacent stunned unit instantly (Not mentioning of dealing damage). So stasis makes the target imune of receiving damage, but not literaly saying giving immunity to die.

And as that ability is the only one I can see in the current squad, that could give any means of stun, at all. But as I only can do the challange once, I don't jsut want to try it out and fail if it doesn't work,

So would a Muton be able to execute an stasised opponent?

Comment: Just out of curiousity, why the challange mode is not worth having its own tag? It gives the game a totally diferent behavior, and this OP i.e. is asking about a setup that AFAIK couldn't even happen in the general mode.

Comment: In case it was due the tag being to general, I hope this is a better fit.

Comment: No reason to have such a specific tag.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: Ok, I take your word. But still I would welcome an explanation, why my previous comment isn't justifyable, or a link on meta that might give general reasons for that.

Comment: Who would benefit from a "challenge mode" tag? It's such a broad topic that there's no reason to have it.

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer: Well my point here is, that this post asks about a setup that can AFAIK only occur in challange mode. So my point is, someone not being into the challange mode probably won't be able to answer anyways. But I might be wrong. So nvm.

Comment: So? You've detailed your problem in the question. The tag would be so broad that it wouldn't make sense to have it.

Comment: @Zaibis This could easily occur in campaign play if a muton and a priest were encountered at once, or if a muton was mind controlled by the player.

Comment: @Studoku: Havent considered mind controll, but I allready aggreed him, so no need for taking it on ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. This does not follow the rules of the game as they are shown to the user:

Stasis does not specify that the target gets stunned. The Stunned status modifier is not applied to characters that are in stasis. Stasis is a different status modifier than Stunned.

> but not literaly saying giving immunity to die

Contrary to games like e.g. Hearthstone, death (which HS calls "destroy") is not separate from taking damage. In XCOM, death only occurs through the act of taking damage. **If you can't take damage, you therefore can't die.**

Even disregarding the portrayed rules and simply thinking about it; what makes you think that the target of a stasis is actually stunned? They could be perfectly aware of everything that is happening.

Comment: Insight full answer. Tho I disagree with your note in the end. Even if some one is totally aware of whats going on while in a stasis, how does it matter to me if someone needs to be imoveable (aka stunned?!) for what I want to do, if he is aware of what I do or not? In the end he can‘t either way do anything to stop me from doing it.

Comment: @Zaibis They can't dodge a grenade either but they still don't take damage from it.

Comment: yeh, but that goes down to the game mechanics again what my OP is about and for what I accepted your answer. But the concept of HP doesnt exist in reallife physics. So I don‘t see why it would matter if I took the consciousness into account ;P

Answer (score 1):

As I couldn't wait to do the challenge, I just gave it a try and figured out, placing the Muton next to a stasised unit and granting him an additional action through inspire, definitely didn't unlock any kind of ability or reaction that harmed the stasised unit in any way. So no, stasis doesn't count for fulfilling the mutons execute requirements.